# Turbolinks and autoplay HTML5 video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, html5-video, turbolinks

I just started a Rails 5 project, and on the homepage I'm supposed to have a video banner, muted, in loop autoplay. I'm using Turbolinks 5 and I don't know if I can keep it.

When I load the home page for the first time, everything works fine. But when I go to any other page, the sound of the home page video starts to play. And If I go back to the home, the sound start again, over the sound previously started.

And so I have multiple instance of the sound of the muted video playing at the same time.

Fun at first, nightmare after 5 seconds.

I've seen this issue: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/177 , which is still open and have no practical solution in the comments.

Apparently it's not new, this post https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6803782 seems to talk about the same problem in 2015. The guy talks about disabling Turbolinks for the link that lead to that page. I can't do it, since my problem is on the home page.

Comment: What happens if you disable turbolinks for the entire site?

Comment: it just works. That's the easy solution, but that's a shame. Disabling Turbolinks is so 2016.

Comment: I agree. But at least it tells you for sure it's a problem somewhere in turbolinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Turbolinks caching a copy of the homepage DOM. Even though the video is not visible it still exists in the cache and so will play. (However, I'm not sure why it's not muted—this *could* be a browser bug :/)

I think Turbolinks could handle this by default, but in the meantime, here are a couple of options:

### Solution 1: Disable Caching on the Homepage

To prevent Turbolinks from caching a copy of the homepage, you could disable caching for that page. For example, you could include the following in your layout's `<head>`:

```
<% if @turbolinks_cache_control %>
  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="<%= @turbolinks_cache_control %>">
<% end %>
```

Then in your homepage view:

```
<% @turbolinks_cache_control = 'no-cache' %>
```

The downside is that you miss out on the performance benefits when the visitor revisits the homepage.

### Solution 2: Track `autoplay` elements

Alternatively, you could track `autoplay` elements, remove the `autoplay` attribute before the page is cached, then re-add it before it's rendered. Similar to [Persisting Elements Across Page Loads](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads), this solution requires that `autoplay` elements have a unique ID.

Include the following in your application JavaScript:

```
;(function () {
  var each = Array.prototype.forEach
  var autoplayIds = []

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
    var autoplayElements = document.querySelectorAll('[autoplay]')
    each.call(autoplayElements, function (element) {
      if (!element.id) throw 'autoplay elements need an ID attribute'
      autoplayIds.push(element.id)
      element.removeAttribute('autoplay')
    })
  })

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-render', function (event) {
    autoplayIds = autoplayIds.reduce(function (ids, id) {
      var autoplay = event.data.newBody.querySelector('#' + id)
      if (autoplay) autoplay.setAttribute('autoplay', true)
      else ids.push(id)
      return ids
    }, [])
  })
})()
```

This script gets all the `autoplay` elements before the page is cached, stores each ID in `autoplayIds`, then removes the `autoplay` attribute. When a page is about to be rendered, it iterates over the stored IDs, and checks if the new body contains an element with a matching ID. If it does, then it re-adds the `autoplay` attribute, otherwise it pushes the ID to the new `autoplayIds` array. This ensures that `autoplayIds` only includes IDs that have not been re-rendered.